# Shouldn't "const references" be actually called "references to const"?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, constexpr

I came up with this feeling when playing with constexpr references. But the issue itself is not related to constexpr, it is merely revealed by it.

We know that there are "pointers to const" and there are "const pointers". BTW, since the latter are much less used than the former, their name is often actually used to reference the former. Anyway, there is no this distinction for references, since they are not rebindable. Thus we only have "const references" and not "references to const". This is the common terminology and it [is used](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#6) in the standard as well. But it does not seem right to me.

Let's take a look at some well-known examples, commented with this common terminology:

```
      int    i = 0;   // Value
      int*  pi = &i;  // Pointer to i
const int* cpi = &i;  // Pointer to const i
int const* cpi = &i;  // Pointer to const i (east-const style)
int* const pci = &i;  // Const pointer to i
      int&  ri = i;   // Reference to i
const int& rci = i;   // Const reference to i
int const& rci = i;   // Const reference to i (east-const style)
```

Now let's take a closer look on several lines from the above:

```
const int* cpi = &i;  // Pointer to const i
const int& rci = i;   // Const reference to i
```

`const int*` declares "pointer to const", while `const int&` declares "const reference". Same order in the declaration, different order in the meaning. There is a clear inconsistency here. But if we call it "reference to const" inconsistency is gone. Same order on both sides.

The tension intensifies with the introduction of `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int& cri = i;  // Constexpr reference to i
constexpr const int& crci = i;  // Constexpr const reference to i
```

"Constexpr const" reference? Huh? The documentation [clearly says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration implies `const`.

A reference is an object. So why would we need `const` when it is already `constepxr`?.. Yet we need it, if `i` is const. Looks frustrating.

But the frustration is no more with help of "reference to const". Let's call `crci` "constexpr reference to const i". Now it is clear that `const` is applied to the referenced object, while `constexpr` is applied to the *reference itself*, stating the fact it can be used in constexpr context. And also that it is const, since all references are const. Makes perfect sense. To make it more consistent with the pointers, we might even have used the following hypothetical syntax:

```
const int& constexpr crci = i;   // Constexpr reference to const i
const int* const      pci = &i;  // Const pointer to const i (perfect consistency)
```

But that's not how C++ works, for better or worse.

This concept of "reference to const" really helped me to understand "constexpr const reference" thing.

What do you think? Does the concept of "reference to const" sound convincing to you?

Comment: Sorry but ... why do you call a `const int &` "const reference to int" and not "reference to const int"? I mean... are you sure that the "common terminology" for `const int &` is "const reference to int"?

Comment: Well, that's what I heard during 11 years of coding in C++, and that's what standard says: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#6

Comment: In this case I'm agree with you (if I understand correctly what you say): is a bad way (a confusing way) to name something that should be named "reference to const int".

Comment: Devil's advocate: you can bind a `const int&` to a non-`const` `int`.

Comment: @Mikhail: What does this question have to do with the C++ standard? That's what the language-lawyer tag means.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Just like you can bind `const int*` to a non-const int. Yet we do say "pointer to const".

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, the standard uses the same terminology.

Comment: It's just easier to say "const reference" instead of "reference to const". A reference itself is always const, so there can be no confusion.

Comment: The Standard also uses the terminology of self-immolation. But I doubt that descriptions of one's self immolation is related to Standard C++.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Devil's advocate v2: you can point a `const int *` to a non-`const` `int`

Comment: This is a language question, but it doesn't seem to be a question about the C++ language, but the English one. In C++, both semantically and syntactically, it works as "reference to const"; people just don't like the extra syllable. In fact, a parallel construction to a "const pointer", like `int & const r = i` isn't a valid construction.

Comment: @rustyx More devil's advocacy: there is at least some confusion, because we sometimes see questions involving surprise that when e.g. `T` is a template parameter with template argument `int&`, `const T` is not `const int&` but `int&`. Though we also see similar questions about pointers, so it's not clear if or how much more precise language would help avoid that confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the proper name for `const int &` is a "reference to `const` `int`".

It's often called a "`const` reference to `int`" (probably because it sounds better to some), but technically that's a misnomer.

Even though they are not rebindable, references themselves are never `const` (i.e. `std::is_const_v` always equals to `false` for a reference).

---

> ```
> constexpr const int& crci
> ```
>
> "Constexpr const" reference? Huh? ... Let's call crci "constexpr reference to const i"

That's correct, `crci` is a "constexpr reference to const i".

---

> To make it more consistent with the pointers, we might even have used the following hypothetical syntax:
>
> ```
> const int& constexpr crci = i;   // Constexpr reference to const i
> const int* const      pci = &i;  // Const pointer to const i (perfect consistency)
> ```

To be honest, I don't see how this proposal improves consistency. `int *constexpr pci;` is not allowed for pointers, so why should it be allowed for references?

Things seem to be reasonably consistent to begin with:

```
constexpr const int *a; // constexpr (and const) pointer to const int
constexpr const int &a; // constexpr (but not const) reference to const int
```

Yes, adding `constexpr` doesn't make a reference itself `const`, but I don't think it needs to be fixed. (What would be the difference between a `const` refenrece and a non-`const` reference?)

Note that `constexpr` is not a part of a type, but it's a property of a variable. (e.g. `constexpr int x;` declares `x` with the type `const int`, and not some hypothetical `constexpr int`).

Comment: "but I don't think it needs to be fixed" - I do not by any means propose to fix the standard, it was just an illustrational example :)

Answer (score 2):

Since volatile tends to be also be relevant, the standard often uses "reference to a cv-(un)qualified" in normative text to cover both qualifiers, which conforms to your preference.

With quick search, besides the code example that you quoted, the standard appears to use (non-) const reference in following places, all in the standard library spec:

> [container.node.observers]
>
> ```
> key_type& key() const;
> ```
>
> Returns: A non-const reference to ...
>
> ---
>
> [rand.req.adapt]
>
> ... The expression a.base() shall be valid and shall return a const reference ...
>
> ---
>
> [futures.shared.future
>
> — (19.1) shared_future::get() returns a const reference to ...

Arguably, the wording could be improved by using reference to const.

---

Outside of the standard, "references to const" *is* used. But so is const reference, which is sometimes chosen possibly due to terseness.

In fact, pointers to const are also colloquially often called const pointers even though that meaning is ambiguous, which easily leads to confusion. In case of references, there is no ambiguity to those who know that references cannot be top level qualified. Beginners won't know that, so the use of "reference to const" is important in introductory material in my opinion. But so is perhaps explanation that const reference is used to mean the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I accepted HolyBlackCat's answer, since it also mentions `std::is_const_v` and `constexpr` not being a part of a type. Which is quite interesting comments IMHO.